# PowerShell (x64) stops working after trying to download EXE files (Windows 7)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-7, powershell-2.0

**CONTEXT:**

- Found a script on SO to download files from URL in PowerShell v2.0 (I am using Windows 7)

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile( 'site.com/file.txt', 'file.txt' )"
```

- Used a batch file `.bat` to run this script inline.
- Works great -- for zip and images!

---

**PROBLEM:** Once I try downloading an `.exe` from URL, the batch file runs WITHOUT executing Powershell script. ***And Powershell.exe stops working completely in Windows 7...***

- Powershell *(x86)* still works, on the other hand.
- Opening powershell.exe (x64) directly from folder: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` only **opens blank window and closes immediately**
- Tried using `sfc /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`, but it's not working because Windows 7 doesn't have that option
- Running the batch script again works, but the powershell part is skipped

I believe it works again after rebooting (haven't tested properly), but I can't seem to make Powershell (x64) work again without rebooting :/ I don't even know what the problem is as I don't know where to start debugging.

This question might be better suited for superuser.com, but I'm asking here first -- thanks for help :)

Comment: Antivirus? Try disabling it

Comment: @JCWasmx86 disabled Malware Bytes and Avast, but still nothing :/ I believe they should have told me if they were blocking a program, but I've got no popup info

Comment: For your sanity's sake.. install [WMF 5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616)

Comment: [3 ways to download files with PowerShell](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell) and ditto on the update to v5x. Even MS has been telling folks to get off v2.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Nvm, you were right, it *was* the antivirus. Tested it extensively after your idea and once Avast was enabled, Powershell (x64) got silently blocked after script execution, and persisted until rebooting.

Comment: @DougMaurer I need to support v2.0 for max compatibility. I'm distributing a batch script and it *should* work on minimum Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

As @JCWasmx86 pointed out, **it was indeed my Antivirus blocking Powershell.**

I tested it extensively with Malwarebytes and Avast in different states -- turned off both of them, then switched them on one by one and ran my script after each state change. Turns out, once Avast got enabled, Powershell (x64, or the *default* one) got silently blocked after script execution, and persisted inactive until reboot or enough time had passed.

This only happened with `.exe` files. Avast must not like scripts downloading unverified exe files from the internet.